# get last message from firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore collection like the following. I need to get the last stored `message`.

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- chat_rooms(collection)
        |
        --- chats(collection, the id for that collection is sender_reciever)
             |
             --- time_send: (millisecondsSinceEpoch)
             |
             --- sender:(string)
             |
             --- message:(string)
```

This is my `db` method to get the last messaeg

```
  getLastMessage(String chatRoomId) {
    return  Firestore.instance.
    collection('chat_rooms').document(chatRoomId)
        .collection('chat').orderBy('time_send',descending: false)
        .limit(1);
  }
```

Here I am calling it. `Chats` is a widget that returns the `sender` and `last_message`. Basically what I am trying to do is, for instance,  while using whatsapp the last message pops on home page.I am trying to do exact same thing. That way, I could get the `username` too. The method below does not return actual user data. Since the collection `chat_rooms_id` has an id that is combination `username` of `sender` and `reciever`. I am just removing the `reciever` which is the current user.And, the `sender` remains.

```
   return Chats(
                      username: snapshot.data.documents[index]
                          .data["chat_room_id"] // return chat_room id
                          .toString()
                          .replaceAll("_", "")
                          .replaceAll(Constants.signedUserName, ""),
                      chatRoomId:
                          snapshot.data.documents[index].data["chat_room_id"],
                      last_message: _db
                          .getLastMessage(snapshot
                              .data.documents[index].data["chat_room_id"]
                              .toString())
                          .data[0]['message']
                          .toString(),
                    );
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need `descending: true` to get the latest value in `.collection('chat').orderBy('time_send',descending: false)
        .limit(1);`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen still getting error like this `Class 'Query' has no instance getter 'data'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Query'
Tried calling: data` ther eror occurs in the last code `last_message` section

Comment: That's because you're not calling `get` (or `.snapshots`) on the query you constructed, as LeadDreamer also mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

You need either

```
    return  Firestore.instance.
    collection('chat_rooms').document(chatRoomId)
        .collection('chat').orderBy('time_send',descending: false)
        .limit(1).get();
  }
```

...although I'll note this returns a PROMISE you'll have to deal with.  You defined a QUERY to the last document, but you did not fetch the query results

Comment: There is a progres but still not working. I am not getting error any more but as a result prints out `Insatnce of 'Future<QuerySnapshot>'`